# Java: Clob to byte[]

Tags: java, sql, arrays, clob

How can I read a java.sql.Clob into a byte[]?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this?  Clobs are character data.  why do you want to convert it to binary data?

Comment: @jtahlborn Maybe to encode the Clob to b64?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

with commons-io

```
byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(clob.getAsciiStream());
```

Comment: We had encoding issues with this one, instead we used `IOUtils.toByteArray(clob.getCharacterStream(), "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 2):

```
int length = clob.getLength();         
 byte[] array = new byte[length];       
 InputStream in = clob.getAsciiStream();       
 int offset = 0;        
 int n;        
 do      
    n = in.read(array, offset, length - offset);        
 while (n != -1);
```

Try the above snippet of code for reading a clob into Byte array.

Answer (score 1):

Get the ASCII stream and then read from the stream into a byte array. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html#getAsciiStream()